# Which HTML control is suited for a blog's standard page?

Tags: html

I want to code and design a blog without using any available scripts. I want to know which HTML control to use to display posts one after the other as in a typical blog.

I am going to use Eclipse to code the same.

Comment: The only possible answer is [mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29).

Comment: @Ash why? It's perfectly possible to update the blog using Eclipse. But admittedly, things like detail views, different sortings, etc. are out of the question this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know which HTML control to use to display posts one after the other as in a typical blog.

Seeing as HTML controls can be styled freely, it isn't as much a big deal as in a client-side GUI. But for a list of blog posts, one suitable element would be [`<ul>` (unordered list)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp), the individual posts being [`<li>` (List items)](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_li.asp?PHPSESSID=5ce4d35d864012f8aced3046c0ee11a3).

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest any links for the same?

Comment: I didn't mean links for <li>, I mean any link where I can find ways to dynamically extend HTML table and create <li>.

Comment: @RPK how do you mean, dynamically? I don't understand. Didn't you want to build your blog in pure HTML?

Comment: No. HTML + PHP. Sorry for the missing tag in OP.

Comment: @RPK well, there is no defined way to do that. Any tutorial on how to build a web application using PHP will show the way I guess - here's one on how to build a blog, but I haven't read it. http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/besserer20050729.php3